# Java: Different outputs when add/remove short and integer elements in a Set

Tags: java, integer, set, short

I wasn't sure on how to ask this question. But, what is the different between these 2 lines of code?

```
Set<Integer> a = new HashSet<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    a.add(i);
    a.remove(i - 1);
}

System.out.println(a.size());
```

I expected **99** to be the output

Output is **1**

---

```
Set<Short> a = new HashSet<Short>();
for (Short i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    a.add(i);
    a.remove(i - 1);
}

System.out.println(a.size());
```

I expected **99** to be the output

Output is **100**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The type of the expression `i - 1` is `int` because all operands in an integer arithmetic expression are widened to at least `int`. `Set<Short>` has `add(Short)` and `remove(Object)` so there's no casting/autoboxing needed on the `remove` call. Therefore you are trying to remove `Integer`s from a set of `Short`s.

Note that for this reason it almost never makes sense to declare a `Set<Number>`:

```
final Set<Number> ns = new HashSet<>();
final short s = 1;
ns.add(s);
ns.add(s+0);
ns.add(s+0L);
System.out.println(ns); // prints [1, 1, 1]
```

As a bonus round, if you change the set implementation to `TreeSet`, the magic disappears and it throws a `ClassCastException`, giving away the trick.

Deep down, this issue has to do with the fact that equality is a symmetric relation, which must not distinguish the right hand side from the left hand side. These semantics are impossible to achieve with Java's single-dispatch methods.

Comment: Whether I do a.add((short)i) or a.add(i) ... my output stays as 100.

Comment: Of course. The conversion operator is not necessary with a `Short` variable. My original answer refers to your original question, which I fixed by introducing the `short` conversion, and you fixed it differently.

Comment: It's not because 1 is an int, it's because the arithmetic expression on the right-hand side of the assignment operator evaluates to int by default. E.G. short i = 1; short j = i + i; won't compile.

Comment: @RobertBain But there's no assignment here. Did you mean to say that *all* arithmetic expressions are at least as wide as `int`? Because that would be correct.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik that's precisely what I was trying to say but for some reason described my own example rather than that in the answer. Glad you knew what I meant!

Answer (score 3):

The first code snippet removes from a `HashSet` of `Integers` all the numbers except for `99` because `98` is last number it removes.

The second code snippet is trying to remove an `Integer` from a `HashSet` of `Shorts`, consequently, it does not remove any element.

On the first code snippet, in the statement `add(i)` the `int` is automatically converted to an `Integer`.

On the second code snippet, if you had done the following:

```
Set<Short> a = new HashSet<Short>();
for (Short i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
     a.add(i);
     a.remove(i);
}
```

It would remove all the elements, since you add and remove a `Short`. However, because you are trying to remove `i - 1`, it will convert `i - 1` to an `Integer`. Hence, trying to remove an `Integer` from a HashSet of `Shorts`, which actually leads to no number being removed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove Integer from Set of shorts without casting.