# Why does this code print 100 instead of 1?

Tags: java

```
public class Short {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set s = new HashSet();

        for(short i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            s.add(i);
            s.remove(i-1);
        }

        System.out.print(s.size());
    }

}
```

Can anyone tell me why it prints 100 instead of 1?

Comment: The fact is, the code won't compile.  You can use a primitive as a generic parameter. Beware calling your classes after classes the already exist

Comment: @MadProgrammer *can't ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer indeed, you can't use a primitive like that, which begs the question of how the OP made the code print anything.  FWIW, if I replace `short` with `Integer` the code compiles, and correctly prints `1`.

Comment: Can you please tell me why it should print `1` instead of `100` ???

Comment: Well, with every iteration you add and remove an element to the set. So theoretically there should always be 1 element present. Hence the size should be 1.

Comment: @1337 Thank you, fat fingers, sticky keyboard...

Comment: @GeraldSchneider But the OP is adding a `Short` and trying to remove an `Integer`...hence the size is `100` ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer You're welcome ;) Just wanted to post an answer but you were faster there :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I know that, I was answering the question of Ankit.

Comment: I think I might steal this for an interview question...

Comment: @khakiout It won't make a difference to the answer, but would greatly remove confusion...

Comment: Can people please be very careful when modifying peoples posts NOT to add additional code into code snippets, regardless if you think they should be there or not, it introduces doubt and confusion into the question which is best addressed by asking comments of the poster - Thanks :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Why did you edit it to the unsafe version?

Comment: @khakiout Wrong, I editted it to a compilable version by changing the primitive short to the wrapper Short.

Comment: @khakiout It does! It compiles perfectly fine and prints 100! ;)

Comment: @1337 Because that's what the original posted version of the code was, some one edited to use `<short>`, which started a lot of confusion. First rule of SO, don't modify posted code ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oh right I just saw it in the revisions.. initally thought the version with <short> was the first version :)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366060/java-different-outputs-when-add-remove-short-and-integer-elements-in-a-set

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There seems to be some auto boxing going on...that is Java is automatically converting between `Object` and primitive...

If I ... rename your class, use `Short` instead of `short` in the initialisation of the `Set` and then use...

```
Set<Short> s = new HashSet<Short>();

for (short i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    s.add(i);
    s.remove(i - 1);
}

System.out.println(s.size());
```

It will print `100`...but why?

To answer that, we need to take a closer look at the `remove` method...

[`Set#remove(Object o)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) expects an `Object`, not the generic type like `add`, but an actual `Object`...when you do `i - 1`, Java assumes that `1` is an `int` and automatically scales the types up and auto boxes it as `new Integer(i - 1)`...which clear does not exist within the `set` (you don't have any `Integer` objects!)

However, if we change `s.remove(i - 1);` to `s.remove((short)(i - 1));`, we force the conversion of the value back to `short` which then gets autoboxed as `new Short(i - 1)`, which does exist in your set and the end result is it will now print `1`...

Simple ;)

Answer (score 2):

Upon running this code, I found that, after converting your primitive generic to `java.lang.Short`, the problem is when you do `i-1`. `short`-`int` returns `int`, therefore the `remove` operation tries to remove an `Integer` from `s`. `int` and `short`, and, respectively, `Integer` and `Short` are very different.