# Program output explanation HashSet

Tags: java, hashset, short

```
Set<Short> set = new HashSet<Short>();
short i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    set.add(i);
    set.remove(i-1);            
}
System.out.println(set.size());
```

When we run above program output comes 100. 
I understood it that As we are inserting short values in set and trying to remove integer value. So It's not removing from set.

But if we modify remove statement as below

```
set.remove(i);
```

Output coming 0. Any idea?

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366060/java-different-outputs-when-add-remove-short-and-integer-elements-in-a-set

Comment: Instead of saying "Output coming something else" can you simply print you see in those cases and also what you expect to see?

Comment: I request please read complete question.

Answer (score 0):

While you are removing it from the set, `i-1` is treated as object and need to be typecast to shore to remove correct value from the set. `set.remove((short)(i - 1))`

```
Set<Short> set = new HashSet<Short>();
short i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        set.add(i);
        set.remove((short)(i - 1));
}
System.out.println(set.size());
```

Try this code its giving output as 1.

Comment: I know that If we cast to short item will be deleted from set. But my question is something else.

Comment: It is just because 1 is by default an integer and not a short, so if i is a short, i - 1 is an int. In the second snippet, i stays a short so the values are removed from the set

Comment: So If I modify set.add(i); to set.add(i+1); will get compiler error.

Comment: Good question, it is probably the case. No time to chek, I got to go. Bye